# DatagramPacket Problem. Pack lenght gets changed to 15 bytes after one succesful message. (UDP, JAVA)

Tags: java, udp, datagram

The problem is quite simple but I haven't found the solution yet (Sorry for bad english, I don't have many opportunities to write in english... so broken english expected, be warned).

I have a simple UDP java code (client) that sends a message via datagrampacket to a another java code (server) and prints the message recieved. The problem is that the first sent message goes well (it prints the data I have sent) but the others packets transforms from 26 bytes to 15 bytes, and this isn't a problem on the variables, nor the client (I guess) because when I print the data.lenght of the message I send this is always 26 (like it should be).

This is my code:

> Client:

```
import java.io.IOException;      import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;     import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class cliente {
    public static final void main(final String[] args) {
        InetAddress  direccion;        DatagramPacket p;        byte[] data = new byte[5024];
        DatagramPacket recibido = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
 
    while(true){
        for(int i=0, k=5; i<k;i++) {
        
            String[] SensoresId = new String[] {"001", "002", "003", "004", "005"};
            
            try {
              direccion = InetAddress.getByName("localhost"); //get local host address
              
              //Grabbing ID of sensor
              String Sen_Id = SensoresId[i];
              //Taking Date of execution and hour
              DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
              Date date = new Date();
              String fecha_ahora = new String(dateFormat.format(date));
              //random parameter
              Random random = new Random();
              int numero_rand = random.nextInt(101);
              String medicion = String.valueOf(numero_rand);
             
              //joining all variables in the message to send
              String mensaje = Sen_Id + "," + medicion + "," + fecha_ahora;
        
                  try(DatagramSocket client = new DatagramSocket()) {  
                    data = mensaje.getBytes(); //allocating the data
                    p = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, direccion, 9984); //create package
                    System.out.println("enviando la data...");//sending the data...
                    client.send(p);  //send message
                    client.setSoTimeout(5000); //waiting a to a timeout 
                    
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            //getting the respond message
                            client.receive(recibido);
                            String mensaje_de_vuelta = "recibiendo de:" + recibido.getAddress() + "," + "mensaje:" + new String(recibido.getData());
                            String respuesta =  new String(recibido.getData());
                            System.out.println(mensaje_de_vuelta + "\n");
                            //Not so important code (work in process)
                            if(respuesta == "duplicados" || respuesta == "OK") {
                                break;
                            }
                            client.close(); //I tried to close the client in hope that will fix it but no
                            break;
                        }catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
                            System.out.println("Se acabo tu tiempo!" + e);
                            client.close();
                        }
                    }
                  
                
                } 
              
            } catch (SocketException e1) {
                System.out.println("Error en socket" + e1);
            }catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
          try {
                
            System.out.println("Esperando 5 segundos...");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
    } 
      
    }

}
```

> Server:

```
import java.io.IOException;      import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;   import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;


public class servidor {
    public static final void main(final String[] args) {
        DatagramPacket  p;      byte[] data = new byte[5024];
    
    try(DatagramSocket server = new DatagramSocket(9984)) { 
     while(true) {
        p = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length); //create package
        server.receive(p); //wait for and receive package 
        System.out.println("Se recibio tu mensaje");
        //System.out.println("New message " + p.getSocketAddress());
        String mensaje_cliente = new String(p.getData(),0,p.getLength()); 
        System.out.println(p.getLength());
            //Make a print to see recieve message 
            System.out.println(mensaje_cliente); 
            //Obtaining adresses
            int puertoCliente = p.getPort();
            InetAddress direccion = p.getAddress();
            
            //preparing the respond 
            String mensaje_vuelta = "Hola como esta?";
            data = mensaje_vuelta.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket respuesta = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, direccion, puertoCliente);
            //sending respond
            System.out.println("Enviando respuesta al cliente...");
            server.send(respuesta);
        
     }
    
    } catch (SocketException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

> Result:

```
 Se recibio tu mensaje
26
001,18,2020/11/18 09:35:30
Enviando respuesta al cliente...
Se recibio tu mensaje
15
002,14,2020/11/
Enviando respuesta al cliente...
Se recibio tu mensaje
15
003,36,2020/11/
Enviando respuesta al cliente...
Se recibio tu mensaje
15
004,59,2020/11/
Enviando respuesta al cliente...
Se recibio tu mensaje
15
005,84,2020/11/
Enviando respuesta al cliente...
```

As you can see the message lenght decreases from 26 to 15, and that makes the message split in half. <--that's my problem.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Have a great day.

Comment: You are replacing the original `byte[] data = new byte[5024];` with a shorter byte array yourself by executing `String mensaje_vuelta = "Hola como esta?"; data = mensaje_vuelta.getBytes();`.

Comment: Big Thanks @ThomasKläger, it was only that. Muchas gracias amigo :3